# Saxon exclude-result-prefixes dropping namespace for attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I have this weird problem with Saxon's XSLT processor (latest version = 9.?)

Given this bogus XML (doesn't matter what it is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="urn:bogus">bogus</root>
```

With this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:b="urn:bogus"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="urn:foobar"
  xpath-default-namespace="urn:foobar"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

 <x:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />   

  <x:template match="b:root">
    <foo xsi:type="xs:string"><x:value-of select="."/></foo>
  </x:template>

</x:transform>
```

Will actually drop the **xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** declaration from the resulting XML because of **exclude-result-prefixes="#all"**. Apparently this happens because it is used in an attribute value and not in an element or attribute.

Removing exclude-result-prefixes="#all" or specifying manually which prefixes to remove does work.

Is this intended behavior? I guess the processor treats all attribute values as random strings and doesn't take namespaces into account for them (it doesn't even notice it has one I assume).

Should there be special behavior for well known attributes like xsi:type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#namespace-fixup requires the processor to check attribute values for type names, as it says:

> Namespace fixup is not used to create namespace declarations for
>   xs:QName or xs:NOTATION values appearing in the content of an element
>   or attribute.
>
> Where values acquire such types as the result of validation, namespace
>   fixup does not come into play, because namespace fixup happens before
>   validation: in this situation, it is the user's responsibility to
>   ensure that the element being validated has the required namespace
>   nodes to enable validation to succeed.

Based on that I would say it is the responsibility of the stylesheet author to ensure that the `xs` prefix is bound to the URI `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.

Comment: Correct response. Certainly with a non-schema-aware processor, there's no way it will recognize an attribute as having QName type (xsi:type could have been treated specially, but it isn't). Even with a schema-aware processor, it's tricky, because as the extract found by Martin points out, you can't validate until you know what namespaces are in scope, and you can't know it's a QName until you have validated. Solving this would require XSLT to use rules for validation that are a customized variant of the rules in the XSD spec, which would be a nightmare.